# better way to start a service from a home screen app widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have the following code in my sample app. I'm starting a service from an app widget when a button is clicked. The service's job is to play a short audio clip that depends on which button was clicked.

The app widget contains two buttons (PREV and NEXT). On click events are handled in onUpdate().

From different guides that I've found online I can start the service in two ways:

1. by creating a broadcast in onUpdate() method and handle it later in onReceive() method of the extended AppWidgetProvider class (as in the sample code for PREV button).
2. or by calling startService() via a PendingIntent in onUpdate() (as NEXT button).

Which of both is better practice or more commonly used? Thank you

```
<!-- widget_player.xml -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/player_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_player_prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_player_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

WidgetPlayer class

```
public class WidgetPlayer extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String ACTION_WIDGET_PREV = "action.WIDGET_PREV";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    final int nPlayerWidgets = appWidgetIds.length;

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_player);

    for (int i = 0; i < nPlayerWidgets; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        updateWidgetPlayer(context, appWidgetManager);

        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent;

        // PREV button
        intent = new Intent(context, WidgetPlayer.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_PREV);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_player_prev, actionPendingIntent);

        // NEXT button (not using a broadcast)
        intent = new Intent(context, PlayerService.class);
        intent.setAction(PlayerService.ACTION_NEXT);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_player_next, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_PREV)) {
        Intent iPrev = new Intent(PlayerService.ACTION_PREV);
        iPrev.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetMetaPlayerIds);
        context.startService(iPrev);
        updateWidgetPlayer(context, manager);
    }

    // handle more actions here

    else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NEXT button code looks more concise so it is better choice if it does what you want. With the PREVIOUS code you have the extra step of receiving the broadcast which appears unnecessary.

You can pass along the id's in the intent to the service if you need those.

Comment: Yes both methods are working fine (haven't encounter any problems yet), that is what I was wondering if there are any good reasons I should go the extra step with the broadcast.

Comment: If you needed to do something else besides start the service when the button was pressed, then you would use the broadcast. Here you are calling updateWidgetPlayer and I'm not sure what that does, but you can probably call it in the service, and it might make more sense there since you can tell if the service completes properly.

Comment: I forgot about updateWidgetPlayer - it is for another widget of the same app that contains despite the buttons and a TextView which is updated on button clicked and receives its data via a call to a static getters in the service.